# Looping with User Input

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I am a newbie to Java programming and I'm working on this self project. I'm wondering how do i loop a user's input then write to a file, but upon entering a text test to see if the input is correct. So here is where I get confused.

```
 System.out.println(" enter what you want to teach me"); // data
        while (!Keyboard.hasNext()) {

            String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
            System.out.println("\n");
            String go = input.nextLine();

            if ( go == "yes"){
                wr.write(lines);
            wr.write("\n");  }

            wr.newLine();
            wr.close();
        }
```

The loop is never reached and I'm lost to why this is happening.

Comment: Change `go == "yes"` to `"yes".equals(go)`.

Comment: The while condition is backwards. It only enters when `Keyboard.hasNext()` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `!` in your `while` statement. If I'm understanding this correctly you want the loop to run until Keyboard has been iterated through. With the `!` being there the loops condition is never true.

Comment: Okay but now the loop never ends. I'm coming from a C++ background and Java's syntax is different in a few ways compared to C++

Comment: If the loop never ends I suggest avoiding the use of a while loop OR thinking of a different condition for the while loops to check that does result in false eventually. Personally I would you a for loop that runs the length of the string. Just to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahhaaa, I've solve the issue. Thanks for your feedback. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Eggz No problem, glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

A couple pointers:

1. Assuming "Keyboard" is a Scanner(System.in), Keyboard.hasNext() will **never** return false - that is, your while loop will never end. This is because the Scanner will just wait for more input; scanning the console is not like scanning a file where there is a finite number of lines.
2. You cannot compare Strings with ==, you must use the equals method. Look this up if you don't understand why, but you must use `if (go.equals("yes")) { ... }`

Comment: Okay but now the loop never ends. I'm coming from a C++ background and Java's syntax is different in a few ways compared to C++

Answer (score 0):

debug it and you will find your answer. If someone gives you a correct code now, you will be stuck like forever in this loop.

Comment: I won't downvote as you don't have enough reputation to comment, but this should be a comment.

Comment: gee Thanks!. Great information for a rookie programmer.